# Pootle updating template

Tags: pootle

I'm using pootle 2.7.1

I've update my template file, the problem is that the new template only reflects on new languages added and not on the languages that are currently present in the project.

What should I do to update the template that the current languages are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template files are only used to initialize new languages via the web UI for the time being, that means you need to update existing localization files out of Pootle, then import them back.

So basically:

1. `sync_stores` to pull the latest state of your translations
2. Merge these with the latest templates using the tool of your choice
3. `update_stores` to import updated translation back to Pootle

Comment: how do I update existing localization files out of Pootle

Comment: This depends on your file format. For gettext PO, this is by the means of using `msgmerge`.